# Is there an elegant way of seeing whether an entire string consists of nothing but matches?

Tags: python, regex

Python 2 (using the re module).

I want to find these matches in a string such as '</51><52>'... but I also want to check that these matches constitute the entire string (NB from the regex pattern you can also see that '<66/>' is another acceptable pattern).

```
match_obj_iter = re.finditer( ur'(</?\d+>)|(<\d+/>)', str )
for match_obj in match_obj_iter:
    print( '# match found: group |%s|' % ( match_obj.group() ) )
```

Of course one way is to check, at each iteration, that the match_obj's end = the previous match_obj's start... and the first one is 0, and the last len( str ).

I just wondered whether there is a better regex procedure to do this (e.g. if I didn't need particularly to iterate through the matches).

Comment: one idea would be to use re.sub, subsitute the patterns you look for by '' and check if the string is empty afterward.

Comment: @TobiasR ... ah yes, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it by taking your regex and checking that this is the only thing that exists between the beginning and end of your string:

```
if re.match(ur'^((</?\d+>)|(<\d+/>))+$', str):
    print 'Matches the whole string'
else:
    print 'Doesn\'t match the whole string'
```

Comment: Note that this is not quite equivalent to checking whether the results of `finditer` cover the whole string, since `finditer` won't backtrack through a previous match. For example, `^(aaa|aa)+$` matches `aaaa`, but using a pattern of `aaa|aa` with `finditer` will only match the first three characters of `aaaa`.

Comment: That's true but it should work for the OP's problem of consecutive `<...>` strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the regex to do that:

```
re.match(ur'^(?:(?:</?\d+>)|(?:<\d+/>))+$', str)
```

This only matches if the string is composed of one or more matches to `(</?\d+>)|(<\d+/>)` with no other characters in the string.

To find 0 or more, just replace `+` with `*`:

```
re.match(ur'^(?:(?:</?\d+>)|(?:<\d+/>))*$', str)
```

Note that I replaced the capturing groups like `(group)` with non-capturing groups like `(?:group)`, which saves memory and makes boolean matches like this faster.